# Connect to Azure Blob storage from Python

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am a novice in Azure and connecting to azure blob storage from azure function python code, the storage container is behind a firewall and I am currently using Access key to authenticate it, and it is working fine. Below is the code for the same

```
         blob = BlobClient(account_url="https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net",
         container_name="xxx",
         blob_name="dwonload_file.csv",                   
         credential="xxxxxxxxA==")
```

Is there a better way to authenticate as the access key will be exposed to others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can (and should) use Azure Active Directory-based authentication. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/authentication-overview#use-defaultazurecredential-in-an-application) for full docs article including example.

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

# Acquire a credential object
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(
        account_url="https://<my_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net",
        credential=credential)
```

Comment: Can't I use access key and store it in Key vault and pass it in Azure Data factory

Answer (score 0):

***I agree with @silent and you can use DefaultAzureCredential method as it  is used for authentication before accessing the Storage objects like blob, table, queue.***

Instead of using Access keys or SAS tokens as they have a chance of theft, You can directly use your Azure credentials to authenticate with your Blob and interact with it.

---

> You can use DefaultAzureCredential method in your python code, and authenticate with your Azure user or service principal directly.

---

In the code, below I have logged into my VS code terminal with my Default azure username and password by assigning the same user Storage Blob Data Contributor role and downloaded the blob in my local machine from storage account.

**Role:-**

[image]

**Command:-**

```bash
az login
```

**Output:-**

[image]

***The DefaultAzureCredential will automatically authenticate with the Azure account logged into your terminal given the user or service principal has access to the storage account:-***

**Code:-**

```py
from azure.identity import  DefaultAzureCredential

from azure.storage.blob import  BlobServiceClient

  

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url="https://siliconstorage123.blob.core.windows.net", credential=credential)

container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("blob")

blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client("Q1.csv")

  

# download blob data into memory as bytes

blob_data = blob_client.download_blob().readall()

  

# save blob data to a file

with  open("Q1.csv", "wb") as  my_blob:

my_blob.write(blob_data)
```

Q1.csv file got downloaded from my blob storage like below:-

**Output:-**

**Portal:-**

[image]

**Local:-**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Siddhesh Can't I use access key and store it in Key vault and pass it in Azure Data factory

Comment: Yes, You can store the access key of your storage account in Key vault by following these documnent - 1) For powershell - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys-powershell 2) For CLI- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys